# CANT START SQL IN XAMPP

Tags: sql, xampp

I am facing some problem while starting sql in xampp. here is the screenshot[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iW4d1.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL is attempting to use port 3306, which is already in use as stated in the error. Go into

> > Config > Service and Port Settings > Change 3306 to any other unused ports

Restart the service and see if it works.

Comment: You are possibly running a second instance of XAMPP. Your MySQL server may be already running successfully.

Comment: Like what @BimalPoudel said. Apologies, missed the part on the port being already used by MySQL.